# Property "id" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance & typeof id is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When I click on the button I get this error up on the console

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Missing required param "id"
```

I'm trying to target the client based on its id from the URL.
This is the list of Clients!

```
<template>
    <div class="page-clients">
        <div class="columns is-multiline">
            <div class="column is-12">
                <h1 class="title">Clients</h1>
                <router-link :to="{ name: 'AddClient' }" class="button is-light mt-4">Add Clients</router-link>

            </div>
            <div class="column is-3" v-for="client in clients" v-bind:key="client.id">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3 class="is-size-4 mb-4">{{ client.name }}</h3>

                    <router-link v-if="typeof id !== 'undefined'"
                        v-bind:to="{ name: 'ClientView', params: { id: client.id } }" class="button is-light">Details
                    </router-link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template
```

> 

This is the ClientView, from where a user can edit the client, but it isn't displaying at all!

```
<div class="page-client">
        <div class="columns is-multiline">
            <div class="column is-12">
                <h1 class="title">{{ client.name }}</h1>
                <router-link :to="{ name: 'EditClient', params: { id: client.id } }" class="button is-light mt-4">
                    Edit
                </router-link>
            </div>

            <div class="column is-12">
                <h2 class="subtitle">Contact details</h2>

                <p><strong>{{ client.name }}</strong></p>

                <p v-if="client.address1">{{ client.address1 }}</p>
                <p v-if="client.address2">{{ client.address2 }}</p>
                <p v-if="client.zipcode || client.place">{{ client.zipcode }} {{ client.place }}</p>
                <p v-if="client.country">{{ client.country }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my route!

```
{
    path: "/dashboard/clients/:id",
    name: "Client",
    component: Client,
    meta: {
      requireLogin: true,
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get access to the url parameters using `$route.params` which is return from a computed property :

```js
computed:{
   id(){
    return this.$route.params.id
   }
}
```

```html
  <router-link v-if="id !== undefined"
```

Comment: It is undefined, the params.id

Comment: Please recheck my edited answer